# Is there a daemon which resolves a service name to a port?

Tags: services, sysvinit, inetd

A DNS server resolves a hostname to an IP address. A program can resolve a hostname to an IP address by calling `getaddrinfo()` which in turn asks a DNS server to do the resolution, if I am correct.

In SysV init, is there some daemon which resolves  a service name  to a port, just like a DNS server?  Does it do that by reading `/etc/services`? Does `getaddrinfo()` also invoke the daemon to perform the resolution?

I know that `inetd` reads  `/etc/services`  to decide which sockets to listen to. But `inetd` doesn't seem to resolve service name to port, does it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that `getaddrinfo()` only calls DNS if `nsswitch.conf` defines it.  The `files` entry reads, directly, from `/etc/hosts`.

Basically, the "name service switch" functions (NSS) look at `/etc/nsswitch.conf` and then may *dynamically load* "libnss" routines.  So, for example, you might have `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files.so.2`, which is the library loaded when `files` is mentioned in `nsswitch.conf`.

For hosts, the `nsswitch.conf` line may read something like

```
hosts: files dns
```

This will tell the name service resolver to load the "nss_files" library (which will look in `/etc/hosts`) and if that fails, load the "nss_dns" library.  It's *that* library that calls out to a DNS server.

For services, the nsswitch.conf line may read something like

```
services:       files ldap
```

This will load the "nss_files" library (which will look in `/etc/services`), and if that fails then load the "nss_ldap" library.

There are various different backends (files, db, ldap, nis, compat, dns...) and they determine how names are resolved.

For an `inet` entry such as

```
service time
{
...
}
```

the `time` value is looked up in the NSS map for `services`.  If `files` is used in `nsswitch.conf` then it will see a line

```
time        37/tcp      timserver
```

which tells `inetd` to bind to TCP port 37.